# Problemas com 'onsubmit' em formulario e função 'setTimeout'

Tags: javascript, html, css, formulário

Quando eu invoco a função 'valida' nada acontece. Qual meu erro? Também preciso fazer com que a mensagem das funções 'valida' e 'like' desapareçam após 5s(não consegui usando setTimeout)

```js
function dislike() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('esconde')[0].style.display = "block";
}

function like() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='text-shadow: 0px 2px lime; color: #333;'>Obrigado!!!</h1>";
}

function valida() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h2>Tentaremos melhorar!</h2>";
}
```

```css
legend {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#azul:active {
  background-color: skyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

#red:active {
  background-color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.btn2 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.btn2:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.esconde {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.bot {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot">
  <h2>Avalie nosso site</h2>
  <button onclick="like()" id="azul">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" style="color: navy;"></span>
  </button>
  <button onclick="dislike()" id="red">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3x" style="color: red;"></span>
  </button>
  <br>
  <div class="esconde">
    <br>
    <legend style="margin-bottom: -10px;"><strong>O que lhe incomoda?</strong></legend>
    <br>
    <form onsubmit="valida()">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="porn" checked>Conteúdo pesado<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="expor">Expôs minha vida íntima<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="desconf">Sinto desconforto aqui<br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn2">Enviar</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me parece funcionar. Retire apenas o `margin-top: -20%;` do seu `.bot`.

Comment: Esse campo ficou no fundo da página e ainda assim não funcionou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz alguns ajustes simples para ver se é o que precisa.

**Obs.:** Quando fui testar precisei remover o `margin-top:-20px` pois para mim não aparecia, acredito que esteja assim pra você devido seu layout.

```
<div class="bot">
    <h2>Avalie nosso site</h2>
    <button onclick="like()" id="azul">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" style="color: navy;"></span>
    </button>
    <button onclick="dislike()" id="red">
        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3x" style="color: red;"></span>
    </button>
    <br>
    <div class="esconde">
        <br>
        <legend style="margin-bottom: -10px;"><strong>O que lhe incomoda?</strong></legend>
        <br>
        <form onsubmit="valida()">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="radio" name="rad" value="porn" checked>Conteúdo pesado<br>
                <input type="radio" name="rad" value="expor">Expôs minha vida íntima<br>
                <input type="radio" name="rad" value="desconf">Sinto desconforto aqui<br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn2">Enviar</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function dislike() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('esconde')[0].style.display = "block";
    }

    function like() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='text-shadow: 0px 2px lime; color: #333;'>Obrigado!!!</h1>";

        encerra('h1');
    }

    function valida() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h2>Tentaremos melhorar!</h2>";
        encerra('h2');
    }

    function encerra(x){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName(x)[0].style.display = "none"
        }, 5000);
    }
```

Criei a função *encerra* com o `setTimeout` de *5* *segundos* conforme você solicitou na pergunta, com isso você chama a função tanto em `valida()` quanto em `like()` passando o parâmetro desejado, como ex: `h1` e `h2`.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu disse nos comentários, eu apenas tirei a `margin-top: -20px;` do `.bot`. Está correto ou deveria acontecer mais alguma coisa?

```js
function dislike() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('esconde')[0].style.display = "block";
}

function like() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h1 style='text-shadow: 0px 2px lime; color: #333;'>Obrigado!!!</h1>";
}

function valida() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('bot')[0].innerHTML = "<h2>Tentaremos melhorar!</h2>";
}
```

```css
legend {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#azul:active {
  background-color: skyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

#red:active {
  background-color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.btn2 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.btn2:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.esconde {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.bot {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot">
  <h2>Avalie nosso site</h2>
  <button onclick="like()" id="azul">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" style="color: navy;"></span>
  </button>
  <button onclick="dislike()" id="red">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3x" style="color: red;"></span>
  </button>
  <br>
  <div class="esconde">
    <br>
    <legend style="margin-bottom: -10px;"><strong>O que lhe incomoda?</strong></legend>
    <br>
    <form onsubmit="valida()">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="porn" checked>Conteúdo pesado<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="expor">Expôs minha vida íntima<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rad" value="desconf">Sinto desconforto aqui<br>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn2">Enviar</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Leia meu comentario

Comment: Acho que o problema é o 'onsubmit'

Comment: @nelson450 Vou te falar que está bastante esquisito. Porque quando eu publico a resposta, não funciona. Porém se você tentar editar meu código aqui no site, na tela de edição funciona. Bem esquisito.

Comment: Acho que é isso: o onsubmit executa o JS enquanto 'envia' os dados, por isso eu via um flash de '<h2>tentaremos melhorar</h2>. vc conhece outro método similar?

Comment: @nelson450 Foi mal. Não tenho muita experiência ainda com formulários. Mas acredito que o mais comum é ser feito via PHP.

Comment: Não sei nada de PHP, estou usando apenas HTML, CSS, e JS